# How to update multiple MongoDB servers simultaneously - direct mode or replica set?

Tags: c#, mongodb, database

I am interested in using MongoDB as a cache servers. I am relatively new to Mongo so bear with me ...
One of the tasks I should perform is the following:
Retrieve records from database and update 2 MongoDB servers. This task only writes to the Mongo servers and doesn't perform "read" actions. The task should run every 250 ms and the amount of the documents to be updated is between 0 - 180 records (relatively small records - each record is a document).
I would like to know how can perform this task using **one update in the code**? (I do not want to loop over the servers and perform an update for each of them)
**One point to mention:** the data in the mongo servers should be read locally at each machine in order to gain as small latency as possible.

**Should I create a replica set?** if so, will the replica set reflect the up-to-date data in each server given frequency of 250 ms?
**Or should I connect to them directly** like `mongodb://server1,server2/?connect=direct` and then perform one update in the code which will be translated to 2 updates - one for each server?

Comment: You could do an journal acked write to the majority but of course other threads of the app could still read old data

Answer (score 0):

Replies inline..

> I would like to know how can perform this task using one update in the code? (I do not want want to loop over the servers and perform an update for each of them)

You can do a bulk insert or multi update. But at the mongod server side, they will be applied in sequence.

> Should I create a replica set? if so, will the replica set reflect the up-to-date data in each server given frequency of 250 ms?

You can't be sure that everything is replicated to secondaries in 250 ms. But, by default all the read goes to Primary ( replica-set ) so you get the up-to-date data.

> Or should I connect to them directly like mongodb://server1,server2/?connect=direct and then perform one update in the code which will be translated to 2 updates - one for each server?

You have to connect like this only 'mongodb://server1,server2?..options'. Update only goes to the primary, and this update is pulled by the secondary from the primary.

Comment: My intention is to put Mongo on each machine so each read action will be done against the localhost. Moreover, if i set replica set and all the writes and reads goes to the primary so what's the use? how can i take advantage of two servers? did i misplace something?

Comment: When You say, keeping Mongo on each machine, you want to put mongo on the application box itself ?

Replicas serves many purposes:
(1) Distribute the reads ( consistency will be the issue, given WriteConcern is not set )
(2) Taking backups and handling manual errors using slavedelay
(3) Running some long task ( say mapreduce )
(4) handling fail-overs ( say primary going down )

Comment: @Yossi If you wish to utilitise the mongods for more than redundancy, aka queries, then you will need to do more than read/write to primary. You would need to read from secondaries, even with `w` set movement of data will be async and even though you can ensure monotonic reads and writes in the performing thread you cannot in subsequent threads, or at least I do not think you can

Comment: @Yossi Also you cannot read/write to the mongods separately, that will break replication

Comment: I am not "locked" on replica solution. i just wanted to know how can I update the two mongo's in one action without iterate over the servers and do update for each one of them. it understand that the replica solution isn't a suitable choice for me. Did i understand you right?

Comment: @Yossi : If the servers are totally different ( i.e. not part of replica cluster ), then you can't update in 1 action/query.